# Laravel 5.5 Contenedores

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, poo, inyeccion-de-dependencias

En Laravel 5, cuando uno crea un modelo con resource controller y migración (`php artisan make:model Environment -mr`) se puede notar que automáticamente se generan los métodos en el controlador.

Ahora bien, si te fijas en cada método creado automaticamente por **Artisan** en el controlador, en algunos casos, tiene un sólo parámetro de tipo modelo, como por ejemplo: `public function edit(Environment $environment) {}`

En el archivo de rutas en routes/web.php tengo definido el recurso como Laravel aconseja (creo):

```
Route::resource('ambientes', 'EnvironmentController');
```

Ahora bien, si yo ingreso a **/ambientes/1/edit** debería realizar el siguiente proceso, ¿no?

1. Se llama al método `edit()` de ***EnvironmentController.php***
2. Se pasa el parámetro **1** al método.
3. El método edit(Environment $environment) automáticamente "bind" el ID con el modelo, y lo llama por medio de ORM.

Bueno, todo eso no sucede. En cambio, me devuelve un objeto `App\Environment` vacío.

La única forma en la que puedo lograr lo que intento es crear las rutas manualmente de la siguiente forma:

```
Route::get('ambientes', 'EnvironmentController@index');
Route::get('ambientes/create', 'EnvironmentController@create');
Route::post('ambientes', 'EnvironmentController@store');
Route::get('ambientes/{environment}/edit', 'EnvironmentController@edit', function(App\Environment $environment) {});
Route::post('ambientes/{environment}', 'EnvironmentController@update', function(App\Environment $environment) {});
Route::post('ambientes/{environment}/delete', 'EnvironmentController@destroy', function(App\Environment $environment) {});
```

De hecho, si intento modificar los métodos en el controlador para recribir ambos parámetros sólo soy capaz de acceder al **$id**:

public function edit($id, Environment $environment) {}

Según el comando **route:list**:

[image: Route List]

Bueno, ¿cómo debería proceder para lograr la inyección del modelo como único parámetro utilizando únicamente el `Route::resource('ambientes', 'EnvironmentController');`?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia en el controlador el nombre de la variable por `$ambiente`, de hecho, puedes ver que tu parámetro tiene el nombre de `{ambiente}` en el `route:list`.

Saludos,

Answer (score -1):

Bueno como indican tus rutas, el parámetro que recibes es `ambiente`.

Este parametros es el singular de lo que pongas en:

```
Route::resource('rutas' , 'MyController'); 
--> el parametro que recibe mi controlador es ruta
```

Comment: eso está claro, pero ¿qué tiene que ver con la inyección de modelos?